# Play sound with AVAudioPlayer and a valid URL

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, avaudioplayer, nsurl

I have a sound file recorded on my iPad. This file is saved in the documents directory. Now I want to play this sound, but I get an error.

I want to play sound like this:

```
NSURL *soundFileURL = [NSURL URLWithString:ulrString];
_audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundFileURL error:&err];
```

soundFileURL is:

```
Printing description of soundFileURL:
/var/mobile/Applications/1824FDFA-18D7-472F-8C4D-16270372F9C9/Documents/Aufnahme-M-bi-1-7.m4a
(lldb)
```

But I get an error:

```
Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=1685348671 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error 1685348671.)"
```

I have also tried following path to the sound file:

```
@"file:///var/mobile/Applications/1824FDFA-18D7-472F-8C4D-16270372F9C9/Documents/Aufnahme-M-bi-1-7.m4a"
```

But this also does't work :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file is malformed. It is reporting to you a `kAudioFileInvalidFileError`.

Try other format such as `.caf` and see if works.

I have had problems with playing `.m4a` in the past for files that were not from iTunes.

Again, try other format first to narrow down the problem. My guess is it would work when you switch to another format, because you code seems fine to me.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes it's true. .m4a only works in simulator in this case. I have switched to .caf with kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC works fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How have you define your `AVAudioPlayer`? It needs to be a property of strong type if you're using `ARC`.

```
    @property (strong,nonatomic) AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;
```

Also, do you set your audio session correctly for the m4a file you want to play?

```
AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
[session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord error:nil];
[session setActive:YES error:nil];
```

Comment: Yes everything is setup like this. In Simulator its working fine :/